# How to make "Calendar" for R Shiny application?

Tags: r, shiny, calendar, label

There are a lot of JS libraries for making Calendar in web applications.

How to make an elegant Calendar solution with labeling dates like in Google Calendar for R Shiny applications?

Thanks!

Comment: [Calendar plot in R using ggplot2](https://r-coder.com/calendar-plot-r/)

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at the  [fullcalendar](https://github.com/rasmusab/fullcalendar) package on github, alternatively you can [Add a Google calendar to your website](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/41207?hl=en)

```
library(shiny)
library(fullcalendar)

data = data.frame(title = paste("Event", 1:3),
                  start = c("2017-03-01", "2017-03-01", "2017-03-15"),
                  end = c("2017-03-02", "2017-03-04", "2017-03-18"),
                  color = c("red", "blue", "green"))

ui <- fluidPage(
  column(6,
         fullcalendarOutput("calendar", width = "100%", height = "200px")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$calendar <- renderFullcalendar({
    fullcalendar(data)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Good solution but it doesn't allow to make labels on dates and save it then. When I clicked on the cells nothing happens